# Doctrine 2 DQL : How to GROUP BY discriminator column (STI)

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, dql

I have following Doctrine 2 STI Vehicle entity which have two child classes named Car and Bike need to count items in vehicles table by vehicle type. (For example; summary of the table: 3 cars, 5 bikes..)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"V" = "Vehicle", "C" = "CarEntity", "B" = "BikeEntity"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="vehicles", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="discr_type_name",columns={"type","name"})})
 */
class Vehicle {
...
}
```

So, i tried following DQL queries but none of them worked:

```
SELECT v, TYPE(v) as vtype, count(v.id) as cnt FROM Vehicle v GROUP BY TYPE(v);
SELECT v, count(v.id) as cnt, TYPE(v) as vtype FROM Vehicle v GROUP BY vtype;
SELECT v, count(v.id) as cnt, TYPE(v) as vtype FROM Vehicle v GROUP BY TYPE(vtype);
```

QueryException:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 10: Error: Expected known function, got 'TYPE'
```

other one:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 83 near 'TYPE()': Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable
```

Any ideas? (Doctrine version is 2.3)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own DQL function. There are working solutions lying around the web, such as this one: https://gist.github.com/jasonhofer/8420677

I used that code and gave it a bit of a facelift:

```php
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

/**
 * Provides a way to access an entity's discriminator field in DQL
 * queries.
 *
 * Assuming the same "Person" entity from Doctrine's documentation on
 * Inheritance Mapping, which has a discriminator field named "discr":
 *
 * Using the TYPE() function, DQL will interpret this:
 *
 * <pre>'SELECT TYPE(p) FROM Person p'</pre>
 *
 * as if you had written this:
 *
 * <pre>'SELECT p.discr FROM Person p'</pre>
 *
 * This conversion happens at the SQL level, so the ORM is no longer
 * part of the picture at that point.
 *
 * Normally, if you try to access the discriminator field in a DQL
 * Query, Doctrine will complain that the field does not exist on the
 * entity. This makes sense from an ORM point-of-view, but having
 * access to the discriminator field allows us to, for example:
 *
 * - get the type when we only have an ID
 * - query within a subset of all the available types
 */
class TypeFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public string $dqlAlias;

    /**
     * @throws QueryException
     */
    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker): string
    {
        $qComp = $sqlWalker->getQueryComponent($this->dqlAlias);

        /** @var ClassMetadataInfo $class */
        $class = $qComp['metadata'];
        $tableAlias = $sqlWalker->getSQLTableAlias($class->getTableName(), $this->dqlAlias);

        if (!isset($class->discriminatorColumn['name'])) {
            throw QueryException::semanticalError(
                'TYPE() only supports entities with a discriminator column.'
            );
        }

        return $tableAlias.'.'.$class->discriminatorColumn['name'];
    }

    /**
     * @throws QueryException
     */
    public function parse(Parser $parser): void
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->dqlAlias = $parser->IdentificationVariable();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

After that, you must register the custom function as [described in Doctrine's manual](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html). [If you're using Symfony, go here.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html)

This gives you the ability to select the value of the discriminator column and use it later in your queries, and works for selection, ordering and grouping alike.

My working snippet goes like this:

```php
$queryBuilder
    ->select('COUNT(DISTINCT entity) AS count, TYPE(entity) AS type')
    ->groupBy('type')
;
```

Pro tip: if you don't want the `type` in your result data, you can use `SELECT TYPE(entity) AS HIDDEN type`